# email sends whole html page(instead of email body) in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm making a contact form. If someone fills in the form, the data (text,subject) should be sent to my mail. Everything works, but when I fill in form and send the email, it sends the whole HTML page (not just the text from the form).

Here's how it looks like

[image: printscreen]

Here's my controller where I send the mail

```
 public function sendEmail(Request $request)
{

    $data["username"] = $request->username;
    $data["email"] = $request->email;
    $data["subject"] = $request->subject;
    $data["mail_text"] = $request->mail_text;

    Mail::send('contact', ["data" => $data], function ($mail) use ($data){

        $mail->to("leribobo@gmail.com")->from($data["email"])->subject($data["subject"]);

    });

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

as I guess it sends 'contact' page, which is first parameter in method

```
 Mail::send('contact' ....
```

Comment: actually laravel [Mail::send](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail) send whole html it not send html inside of body tag it sends the whole html in that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually sending the `contact.blade.php` file. This is not how we should send a mail.

```
Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function ($message) {
    //

     $message->from('us@example.com', 'Laravel');

     $message->to('foo@example.com')->cc('bar@example.com');
});
```

You've to make a file in `emails.contact.blade.php` and pass `$data` to the blade file as showed above.

Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#sending-mail

Comment: thanks for reply. can you please tell me, i only want to send  mail(f.e. if someone fills in form and sends mail, this mail should come in my gmail's inbox ) so now i should create another contact.blade.php file or just create emails folder and put there my contact.blade.php file ?

Comment: Create a `contact.blade.php` file in your email folder. Now create an html code block in that page where you substitute the `$data` values. This file is actually sending to the email.